# Raspbian QGIS 3.x Install

Tags: qgis, linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install QGIS 3.x on Raspbian Stretch with Desktop - I successfully installed QGIS 2.x using the QGIS sources as described in their install instructions.

I found this build-from-source [guide](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.github.com/qgis/QGIS/master/doc/INSTALL.html) using this [forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=216187), but my linux-fu is weak. I'm wondering if anyone has found a simpler way of getting a standard QGIS 3.x desktop install on Raspbian Stretch?

I'm particularly confused by the 'build Debian package' option when building from source - what previous sections do I skip (if any)?

Comment: I've looked some more and I'm considering following standard install instructions but targeting the "sid" build, which as per the debian package repo (https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=qgis) is 3.x. But it's unstable. I'll update with its stability (ie, usable or not) for future reference.

Comment: Seems the unstable build doesn't support RPi armhf architecture. I'm trying to follow the build from source guide and I'll update if I manage to get that working...still a few dependencies short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative to building from source.

**Issue**: with the QGIS install [instructions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html) (assuming I followed them correctly) - it was unable to find the `python3-qgis` package.

**Solution:** basically use a different mirror than what the install recommends.

Starting from a fresh Raspbian Stretch with Desktop install.

Run: `sudo apt-get update`

Run: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

- Uncomment the `deb-src` line (not sure this matters).
- Add the following line: "`deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian sid main`" (alternative mirrors can be found [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/armhf/qgis/download)).

Run: `sudo apt-get update`

Run: `sudo apt-get install qgis python3-qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

- This will install ~300 packages, and can take a while (~4min to download for me). After the download there is a changelog/notice that must be read (keep pressing return then q). Soon after starting the download there is a prompt...once you're past that you should be safe to step away while it installs.

Once done you can launch QGIS (3.4 Madeira LTR as of this writing) by simply typing `qgis` from the terminal.